# System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is not a valid Win32 program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am developing a C# program with visual studio that makes use of the sql compact library. On the developing computer everything works like a charm but on my home computer that has an almost fresh win8 installment I get a System.BadImageFormatException: is not a valid win32 program and I have no clue why.

I have added the Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact package with nuget. this package includes the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll.

I have also seen on my development computer in the output window of visual studio that the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is loaded from GAC. Since my home computer has a fersh win8 installment it does not have the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll in its GAC but since I have added the Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact package with nuget that should not be problem right?

Comment: You are using the x64 bit DLLs on a x86 system, I guess

Comment: I have added the dll package through nuget. I think that they are compiled with target "any cpu" at least that's what corflags says. My project is set to x86 (32 bit). So I thought that I ran the dll:s in 32 bit mode. But obviously there is some dll:s that are running in 64-bit mode. Is there a sql server compact library specificly compiled for win32?

Comment: Yes, the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is AnyCPU, but it will load the required native DLL files (x86 or x64) based on your OS. But there can be issues http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/12/the-trouble-with-any-cpuprefer-32.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your program or one of it's dependancies is 64 bit and you are running it on a 32-bit computer.  Go to the project properties, and set the "platform target" to either "Any CPU" or "x86" if you are planning to run it on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Thx for the answer roryap. But the project is allready set to x86